# Is there a public server to see public key pinning headers?

Tags: ssl

What I want is see what are headers are exchanged during connection between client (my laptop) and public server with public key pinning. Now I am wondering if there is a public pkp server where I can do my test. I want to know if there is a way to test this situation with openssl.

Regards.

Comment: `openssl s_client` (which you probably mean) does neither speak HTTP nor does it care about HPKP which is a HTTP(S) specific thing.

Comment: So, how can I make some tests in order to see exchanged header during connection to server with pkp enabled? Thanks.